# How to change the icon on the button?

Tags: angular, primeng

There is a button that opens the side menu. I want to change the icon to a button depending on the menu that is open or not. That is, if the window is active, then the icon on the button `pi pi-lock`otherwise `pi pi-lock-open`. How to do it?

html:

```
...
<p-button (click)="_toggleOpened()" icon="pi pi-lock"></p-button>
...
```

ts:

```
  private _opened: boolean = true;
  private _toggleOpened(): void {
    this._opened = !this._opened;
  }
```

Comment: Try `<p-button (click)="_toggleOpened()" icon="{{ _opened ? 'pi pi-lock' : 'pi pi-lock-opem' }}"></p-button>
`

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal Thanks

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal that should do the trick, just a minor correction, it should most likely mean `pi pi-lock-open`, not `pi-lock-ope*m*`.

Comment: @SaschaM78 yes, it's a typo, thanks.

Comment: Did Sarthak's recommendation solve your question? If so, please let us know so that @SarthakAggarwal can write an answer for you to mark it as solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<p-button (click)="_toggleOpened()" [icon]="icon_val"></p-button>
```

TS:

```
icon_val: string="pi pi-lock"
private _opened: boolean = false;

private _toggleOpened(): void {
    this._opened=!this.opened
    if (this._opened)
        this.icon_val="pi pi-lock-open"
    else
        this.icon_val="pi pi-lock"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make icon attribute as property binding and assign ur "pi pi-lock" to a Variable in .ts,

make ur condition as ur requirement

```
    <p-button (click)="_toggleOpened()" [icon]="pi pi-lock"></p-button>


    ts file:
    variable="pi pi-lock"

     private _opened: boolean = true;
      private _toggleOpened(): void {
        this._opened = !this._opened;
if(!this.opened)
{
this.variable="pi pi-lock-open";
}
else{
this.variable="pi pi-lock"
}
      }
```